# Finding eigen values of a binary matrix with diagonal elements are all 0s and non-diagonals are 1s

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find the eigen values of an $n$x$n$ matrix whose diagonal elements are all 0s and non-diagonal elements are all 1s ?

Please don't tell the solution. I just want a hint.

Comment: @julien OP asked to not tell him the solution, just a hint. I think your "hint" went a bit too far towards the solution.

Comment: @VedranŠego Oops...sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The vector $(1,1,\cdots,1)$ is one eigenvector. You need $n-1$ more (counting with multiplicity). Consider your matrix plus the identity.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  row echelon operations to Compute $\det(A-xI)=\begin{pmatrix}
     -x & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
     1 & -x & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -x    
     \end{pmatrix}$;

$$\forall i, ~~ 2\le i\le n :~~~~~~~C _1-C _i,~~~~~~ R_1+R_i$$

wherein $R$ stands for **row** and $C$ stands for **column**.  Now;

$$\det(A-xI)=(-x+(n-1))(-x-1)^{n-1}\color{red }{\longrightarrow} x=n-1  ,-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Generalise. Consider $A=aI+b\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T$ instead, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the all-one vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. Multiply both sides by a nonzero vector $v$ on the right. If $Av=\lambda v$, can you solve for $\lambda$?